# Easy way to get size of Leaflet LayerGroup?

Tags: mapping, leaflet

Is there a straightforward way to get the number of layers in a [Leaflet LayerGroup](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#layergroup)? A quick glance at the documentation says there isn't at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Updated Answer

Since my first answer, the `LayerGroup` has been extended with a `getLayers()` method, making the solution straightforward:

`layerGroup.getLayers().length`.

---

## **OLD** REDUNDANT ANSWER:

Looking at the [LayerGroup code](https://github.com/CloudMade/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/LayerGroup.js), you should be able to get the number of layers by `layerGroup._layers.length`.

But note that `_layers` by the implementors is intended to be private, so I guess you cannot be sure this will work in future versions.

If you want to stay within the public API, then you could call `eachLayer` and count the layers.

Comment: @sidonaldson - you are right. I incorrectly assumed that _layers was an array. I updated the answer to reflect the new API. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Asborn hinted at you can access the maps layer object through any layer event object.

e.g.

```
map.addEventListener('viewreset', function(event){
    console.log(event.target._layers);
}, false);
```

to get the length you would need to count the keys and the easiest way is you use ECMA (chrome, node etc)

```
Object.keys(map._layers).length
```

I'm surprised there isnt a API to get this info such as

```
maps.getLayers();
```

:)

EDIT: actually there is: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup

```
getLayers()
```

and it returns an array of the layers within that group.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to get all functions related to leaflet or another by just typing the variable name or function name or leaflet layer name.

```
 here I used google chrome console manager.
 just type the layer name you will get all the functions related to it
```

***pls look at the below pic*** : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LDz0.png