# Leaflet js: How to count the layers in Layer Group?

Tags: count, leaflet, layer

I would like to make such a map that only allows checking/showing 2 layers at a time and it should show some warning if chosen more.

After searching the internet, and taking a look at these possible solutions and references: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188522/easy-way-to-get-size-of-leaflet-layergroup), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817911/leaflet-layer-control-select-layer-inside-layer-group), [third](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup) etc.
...I still can't get my code to do this simple thing: to **count the layers in a layer group** and according to that, to show a message.

Here my code:

```
    var NumbActive = new L.layerGroup();
    NumbActive.addTo(map);
    map.on('overlayadd',function(active){
    if (active.layer===LAY1){
        NumbActive.addLayer(LAY1);
    }});
    map.on('overlayadd',function(active){
    if (active.layer===LAY2){
        NumbActive.addLayer(LAY2);
    }});
    map.on('overlayadd',function(active){
    if (active.layer===LAY3){
        NumbActive.addLayer(LAY3);
    }}); 

    size = NumbActive.getLayers().length;
        var options = { timeout: 5000 };
        var box = L.control.messagebox(options).addTo(map);
    if (size >2){  
        box.show( 'Please choose only 2 layers at the same time!' );
        };
```

I am also using [this plugin](https://github.com/tinuzz/leaflet-messagebox/blob/master/README.md) for showing messages, which normally works fine, but in this case not at all.

I thought that `layerGroup.getLayers().length` should give a number as a result (length of an array)? It should work but somehow it doesn't.

Please tell me your suggestions. It can't be that complicated. I would just like to know if I'm making some minor mistake that's possible to be corrected or should I write some new function/search for a plugin.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "It should work but somehow it doesn't." is not a good error description. Do you have an actual error message?

Comment: Hello Ivan! Well there is no error shown in console. The problem is that no layer is being added to NumbActive layer Group. I added this part to count the layers added and it stays 0 for this group: 
`let j = 0;
 NumbActive.eachLayer(function(){ i += 1; });
  console.log('NumbActive has', j, 'layers.');`
Whereas for the whole Map it counts well (there are 2 layers I've added, baseMap and overlayLayers{ ... }

So error must be around adding layers to this group... Please give me any inputs that come to your mind. Tnanks!

Comment: When does `NumbActive.getLayers()` run?

Comment: I guess this problem turned into "how to add layers into LayerGroup"? Any inputs on that part in the code? I am trying  this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389595/cant-add-layers-dynamically-to-layer-group-when-click-checkboxes-using-leaflet)this now. But it hasn't been found a solution for that problem...

Comment: I'm not sure if and when  `NumbActive.getLayers()` runs and how to check ..? Sorry, I'm a beginner.  But I assume the loop I wrote above can be a substitute for gettinga number of layers in the group? So the main problem seems to be the group staying empty. Or am I mistaken?
Thanks!

Comment: Debug, debug, debug. You don't seem to be confident in knowing the flow of your code (which thing executes when). Debug your event handlers, set breakpoints, put `console.log()`s everywhere. When you learn when each piece of event-based code runs, everything will be clearer.